# iTextSharp - PDF Resolution changing to a bizarre size when printing

Tags: c#, itext

We use iTextSharp in a very simplistic manner in our system.  Our Web API takes a series of images from our database, then creates a graphic from those images, then saves the single png created image into a pdf file for printing. (it prints an employee badge)  I have code set to a DPI of 300.  The image we generate, then put on the pdf is 952x584 pixels.  This results in 4 perfect barcodes.

[image]

No matter what settings I give though through iTextSharp, the resulting pdf, in print preview, says it has a print area of 13.2" x 8.1" (inches). The only way to get it to print the entire document, is to 'shrink to page', which blurs the barcode.  (we basically print to a CR80 size)

[image]

```
        var doc =
            new Document(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, (float)bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Width,
                    (float)bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Height), 0, 0, 0, 0);

                var front = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bdgDesignDto.BdgFrontImage);
                front.SetDpi(300,300);
                front.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
                front.ScaleToFitLineWhenOverflow = false;
                front.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION;
                front.ScaleAbsolute((float)bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Width, (float)bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Height);
                doc.Add(front);
```

I have changed/removed/added several different properties to variable 'front', but nothing changes the end result.  (except Scale, which we don't want, but did indeed change the final result)

I did change our code up to iText7, but it was so much more complex than what we need, and it didn't work, so I went back to the iTextSharp code and sdk.

If somebody could help me to get the entire page to print without shrinking it, that would be great.

Comment: I did struggle with this a lot in a project, i cant tell you anything but bad news. It's as if it ignores itextsharp wishes you have to use the printing properties of the OS. In my case it was the difference between printing a legal or A4 page paper size

Comment: What values are in `bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Width` and `bdgDesignDto.BdgLayoutFront.Height)`?

Comment: Height = 584, Width = 952